# User created R functions : Export en-masse to new load on new computer

Tags: r

I have many user-defined and created functions in R which I built using `edit()` and `fix()` and viewable using `objects()`. I want to locate them and export them en-masse to a new computer. They neither seem to be located in the C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library directory nor in the C:/Users/Name/My Documents/R/win-library/3.5 directory. In searching Windows using their object names in R (e.g., my.eda2), they do not seem to be stored in any text format.

It is possible to do this one-by-one by opening the function in R, again using `edit()` or `fix()`, copying the function into a text document, and then doing the same thing on the other end to import them. That is really quite tedious, given that I have perhaps 100 functions I would like to migrate.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like RStudio. Also have you checked out exporting the workspace?

Comment: Your functions could be glued together into a package, as described here: https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/